# Yii2 Autocomplete : Save the ID instead of value

Tags: php, yii-extensions, yii2

I have a list of array called as datalist which contains the name of companies with id.when i use it with the typeahead widget,it captures the value of company with the variable coSearch(id of input).but i want to display the list of companies and when selected,it must give the vale of that id in variable .i am really messed with this problem working from three days.Please help me out.
Here is the code for my activeform which contains the widget.

```
<?php 
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['search'],
    'method' => 'get',
    ]); 
    $dataList=ArrayHelper::map($companies, 'id', 'name');
    echo Typeahead::widget([
    'model' => $companySearched, 
    'name'=>'coSearch',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Search  company','id'=>'searchCompany1','class' => 'form-      control','value'=>'1'],
    'pluginOptions' => ['highlight'=>true],
    'dataset' => [
        [
            'local' =>  $dataList,
            'limit' => 10,
        ]
    ]
]);


?>
```

Comment: you can use jquery autocomplete. it is simple.
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved with the help of a hidden field.I use `autocomplete` here

```
<?php
use yii\web\JsExpression;
use yii\jui\AutoComplete;

$data = Company::find()
->select(['name as value', 'name as  label','c_id as id'])
->asArray()
->all();

echo AutoComplete::widget([
'name' => 'Company',
'id' => 'ddd',
'clientOptions' => [
'source' => $data,
'autoFill'=>true,
'minLength'=>'4',
'select' => new JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {
    $('#model-company').val(ui.item.id);
 }")],
 ]);
 ?>

 <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'company')?>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: what is the #model-input here and ui.item.id ?? unable to get these values for me

Comment: @Nishank #model-input is the hidden input field's id and ui.item.id is the    id of the selected value.

Comment: I have an array but when putting it in source .its not working,but on printing it !! its working perfect

Comment: @Nishank make sure your array contains the value,label and id for each element!

Comment: Get more information in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385855/yii2-jui-auto-complete-widget-how-to