# Yii2: Jui Auto Complete Widget how to?

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, yii2

I am trying to use yii2 Jui autocomplete widget.

I have this code which is showing the auto-complete date correctly, but I am not able to save the data.

```
$data=ArrayHelper::map(State::find()->all(), 'id', 'state_name' );
$data=array_merge($data);
```

And then

```
echo 'State' .'<br>';
  echo AutoComplete::widget([
    'model'=>$model,
    'attribute' => 'state_id',     
    'clientOptions' => [
        'source' => $data,        
    ],
]);
```

Any solution will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, it goes like this:

```
use yii\jui\AutoComplete;
use yii\web\JsExpression;
```

Then:

```
$data = State::find()
    ->select(['state_name as value', 'state_name as  label','id as id'])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Then

```
echo 'State' .'<br>';
  echo AutoComplete::widget([
    'name' => 'State',    
    'id' => 'ddd',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'source' => $data, 
        'autoFill'=>true,
         'select' => new JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {
        $('#city-state_name').val(ui.item.id);//#City-state_name is the id of hiddenInput.
     }")],
     ]);
```

and Finally:

```
<?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'state_name')?>
```

That is all.
Hope some one will find it useful.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, there is a way to implement the based model validation on autocomplete field? Thx